# Visualización incompleta de Font Awesome en Firefox y Chrome

Tags: html5, google-chrome, firefox, font-awesome, github-pages

Estoy desarrollando mi sitio [antoniomendiola.com](http://antoniomendiola.com) y en el footer tengo un menú de redes sociales. Uso una lista desordenada y en cada elemento de la lista un SPAN con la fuente de Font Awesome que corresponde al icono de cada red social (facebook, twitter, youtube, github, stackoverflow y linkedin - En ese orden).

Cuando lo visualizo en local sí se visualizan correctamente los iconos en todos los navegadores que tengo (Chrome, Firefox, Edge e IE). El problema es que al estar en línea (alojado en GitHub Pages) No se ven los primeros 2 iconos (facebook y twitter) los demás sí. Esto pasa sólo con Chrome y Firefox de escritorio.  Si entro al sitio con Edge o IE sí se ve el menú completo. También desde el móvil con Chrome sí se ve correctamente.

Cual será la causa??? Si estoy abriendo la página en local y la que está en GitHub Pages con la misma versión del navegador en la misma PC.

Comment: Hola, ¿Hiciste `inspeccionar elemento` a ver cual es el problema con la imagen/char?

Comment: Parece que ya resolviste tu problema. Si es así es aconsejable poner como respuesta la solución del mismo para poder ayudar a otros de la comunidad que se encuentren con una situación similar...

Comment: Así es, ya encontré el problema. No era mi código sino el maldito Adblock Plus. Explico lo que pasó en la siguiente respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Después de buscar por la red, encontré que el problema de que no se vean los iconos de Facebook y Twitter (entre otros de varias redes sociales) de Font Awesome, es causado por una *lista de bloqueo* del Adblock Plus llamada **Fanboy's Social Blocking List.**

[image: Advertencia en la página de Font Awesome]

Según ésta advertencia en la página de Font Awesome, se deben modificar los nombres de las clases de los iconos que se están bloqueando en el archivo **font-awesome.min.css** por uno personalizado para evitar el bloqueo.

Por ejemplo, si usamos el icono de facebook cuadrado:

```
.fa-facebook-square:before {
  content: "\f082";
}
```

Modificar la clase con un nombre diferente:

```
.my-fa-facebook-square:before {
      content: "\f082";
    }
```

Y en el HTML modificamos también el nombre de la clase:

```
<span class="fa my-fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

En el navegador basta con deshabilitar la lista desde las opciones del AdBlock Plus. O Deshabilitar AdBlock Plus en la página que usa FontAwesome.

Con la lista habilitada no se ven los iconos de facebook y twitter.
Aquí si deshabilitamos la lista ya se pueden ver:
[image: Fanboy's Social Blocking List deshablitada]